# Can I bring my laptop, camera on flight to USA?

Tags: air-travel, usa, hand-luggage, electronic-items, event-based-effects

I am going to the US in the coming week. However, I heard that laptop and camera are not permitted to bring on board as carry-on. What are the latest rules about these larger electronics?

Comment: The new rules seem to be very much in flux, or perhaps not fully issued yet, as one airline deleted their announcement of them. It's unclear exactly who this will apply to and for how long. It's probably best to keep checking for updates, but there aren't a lot of specifics right now.

Comment: While the OP would get a more accurate yes/no if the question included a departure country, any answer would naturally list the 6 (or 8: US vs UK) countries, therefore it is possible to answer the question without this clarification. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

A new order has been issued for airlines flying from some Middle Eastern countries that have direct flights to the US, that anything larger than a cell phone shall not be permitted in the cabin and must be checked in.

> The ban, on devices larger than a mobile phone, affects nonstop
>   flights to the U.S. from 10 international airports in cities including
>   Dubai, Abu Dhabi, Doha, Kuwait City, Istanbul and Cairo, the
>   Associated Press reported, citing a U.S. official it didn’t identify.
>   The indefinite ban would impact nine Middle Eastern airlines, a second
>   official told the AP.
>
> The ban would exclude mobile phones and medical devices, Royal
>   Jordanian said. Cameras, DVD players and electronics games along with
>   tablets and laptops must be carried in checked baggage only starting
>   March 21, the airline said.

Source: [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/politics/articles/2017-03-21/mideast-airlines-say-new-u-s-restrictions-will-force-changes)

---

2016-MAR-21

The UK has announced similar flight restrictions:

> Britain has introduced restrictions on carry-on electronic goods on
>   direct inbound flights from Turkey, Lebanon, Jordan, Egypt, Tunisia
>   and Saudi Arabia for the safety of the public, a spokesman for Prime
>   Minister Theresa May said on Tuesday.
>
> Earlier, the United States imposed similar restrictions on planes
>   coming from 10 airports in Muslim-majority countries in the Middle
>   East and North Africa in response to unspecified security threats.
>
> "Direct flights to the UK from these destinations continue to operate
>   to the UK subject to these new measures being in place," the spokesman
>   told reporters. "We think these steps are necessary and proportionate
>   to allow passengers to travel safely."
>
> Passengers would not be allowed to bring phones, laptops or tablets
>   over 16 cm in length, 9.3 cm in width and with a depth of over 1.5 cm
>   into the cabin. These items would have to be in checked-in hold
>   luggage, he said.

Source: [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-airlines-electronics-idUSKBN16S1TG)